# Getting all child records based on parent table record

Tags: sql

I have following tables and relationship:

[image]

And I need to fetch records as below:

[image]

I am not sure how will I get it. I am trying with following query but it is showing 3 records only.

```
SELECT A_NO, B_NO, C_NO
FROM 
(
    (SELECT * FROM S_A) A Full Outer Join
    (SELECT * FROM S_B ) B on A.ROW_ID = B.A_ID   FULL OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM S_C) C on A.ROW_ID = C.A_ID
)
WHERE A.ROW_ID = '1'
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your schema, desired results, and attempt!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is no relationship between S_A->S_B and S_A->S_C here, [a UNION is the right way to go.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/54308/3)

```
SELECT 
    S_A.A_ID,
    S_B.B_NO,
    NULL as C_NO
FROM
    S_A INNER JOIN S_B on S_A.A_ID = S_B.A_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    S_A.A_ID,
    NULL as B_NO
    S_C.C_NO
FROM
    S_A INNER JOIN S_C on S_A.A_ID = S_C.A_ID
```

I suppose [you could do this with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/54308/2) a `FULL OUTER JOIN` but It's clunky, confusing, and is probably not going to be any faster for processing since you'll have to `COALESCE()` and join on subqueries.

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(T1.A_ID, T2.A_ID),
  T1.B_NO,
  T2.C_NO
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
        S_A.A_ID,
        S_B.B_NO,
        CAST(NULL as int) as C_NO
    FROM
        S_A INNER JOIN S_B on S_A.A_ID = S_B.A_ID
  ) as t1
  FULL OUTER JOIN
  (
    SELECT 
        S_A.A_ID,
        CAST(NULL as int) as B_NO,
        S_C.C_NO
    FROM
        S_A INNER JOIN S_C on S_A.A_ID = S_C.A_ID
  ) as t2 ON t1.A_ID = T2.A_ID AND T1.B_NO = T2.B_NO
```

Comment: Well... it's the only way you are going to get the results you want. It shouldn't be any worse then `FULL OUTER JOIN` on three derived tables like you are were aiming at in your attempt. To narrow down on `A.Row_ID='1'` you'll need to stick a `WHERE` in both Select statements. It should be pretty snappy.

Comment: Can we achieve this with inner query ?

Comment: I've written a `FULL OUTER JOIN` example, but I believe the first `UNION` query is going to be faster and easier to read, maintain and scale.

Comment: Can we have a single where clause in the first query ?

Comment: You could wrap that thing up and turn it into a subquery, then apply the WHERE to the main query. Depending on the DBMS optomization, that should (I would hope) get pushed down in the SELECT of the subqueries.